# In-App billing with gradle productflavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, in-app-billing, android-productflavors

I recently imported my project from Eclipse to Android Studio and integrated Gradle's projectFlavors to support the different environment (DEV, QA and PROD). Although I encountered a problem with my in app billing. It seems to use the package name to query the google store but depending on my productFlavors the package name changes.

my gradle.build definition

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        Prod {
            packageName 'com.test.app'
        }
        Qa{
            packageName 'com.test.app.qa'
            versionName '1.2-QA'
        }
        Dev{
            packageName 'com.test.app.dev'
            versionName '1.2-DEV'
        }
    }
}
repositories{
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.test.android:infra:1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23@aar'
    compile files('libs/adgear-android-sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don't *have* to change the package name for each flavors. That would solve your problem, though you won't be able to install the different variants on the same phone at the same time.

Comment: Yes indeed it would solve my problem but I would like to install do both install different variants on the same phone + use google in app billing

Answer (score 0):

You gotta change the packageName property to applicationId.

```
productFlavors {
    Prod {
        applicationId 'com.test.app'
    }
    Qa{
        applicationId 'com.test.app.qa'
        versionName '1.2-QA'
    }
    Dev{
        applicationId 'com.test.app.dev'
        versionName '1.2-DEV'
    }
}
```